# How much can a regular iOS application make anually in the app store?

Tags: ios

This is a very general question. I'm asking because I want to know in advance if it's worth the time and money to jump into this market?

Apple's iOS developer program costs $99/year. MonoTouch looks good but costs $399/year (I feel comfortable with .NET). That's $500/year. So for an app priced at $1 needs to sell 500+ copies per year? How likely is it to achieve this number? How about free app with ads? Is there any extra cost?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I feel that the iPhone ship has sailed, for the most part.  While we did get some decent sales from our "iAmbigram" app for the first 3 months or so back in early 2009, the sheer onslaught of apps in the app store make it all but impossible to get located (even if you have a pretty darn good app).

We spent about $3.5k to develop the app, and have basically broken even over the course of 2 years.  It wasn't the windfall we were hoping for, but I understand that few apps are.  We have a second app in the store which was pretty much a total loss (at $.99, even).

The problem, as I see it, is discoverability.  Unless you have a killer app, people will not know about it, and you will suffer in obscurity forever.  At least on the web, you can do some basic SEO and rank high on Google and make some $$ that way, but on the iPhone... there is no similar mechanism.

Anyway, I wanted to share our case study.  Believe it or not, it's not easy to make back even a small $500 on iPhone apps these days (which was certainly NOT the case in 07 and 08).